# Mobile menu diagnosis?

Tags: ce-1.9.1.0, jquery, menu, mobile

My [mobile menu](http://www.ironsightprecision.com/products/firing-pins/) just stopped working yesterday. This is a Multi-site install, and its only affecting one site.  There has been no installs, no changes to the the site in a few weeks.  There's no error reports, no logs to indicate any issues.  How to fix a javascript or  jQuery issue?

http://www.ironsightprecision.com/products/firing-pins/

[image: Page errors]

The third error only shows after you try to open the mobile menu.

Comment: Most likely an issue between Prototype and jQuery. Make sure `jQuery.noConflict()` is called somewhere. Have you tried cleaning your cache?

Comment: Yes manually and via the admin.  Am using magepsycho  lightbox module, but see no conflict with it.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the tools provided by your browser to inspect content and see errors in console you'll find you have some javascript error specifically 
scripts.js:86 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tooltip is not a function

Comment: I do see this now, thank you.  Do you have any recommendation as to what to do about it?  Update of jquery or javascript?

Comment: first check that actually the function exists in the javascripts you have, if they do check the order they are added to your page so that are not called before being loaded. and this kind of error for sure you've changed something inside the code so i would check what change broke you code.